# When is const optional in Dart 2?

Tags: dart, dart-2

In Dart Object() constructor is declared as *const* so:

```
identical(const Object(), const Object()); //true
```

I know that in Dart 2 the keyword *const* is optional and I thought that the previous statement was equivalent to:

```
identical(Object(), Object()); //false
```

But actually it seems to be equivalent to:

```
identical(new Object(), new Object()); //false
```

Now my doubts are:

1) When is *const* keyword optional?

2) Is there any way to ensure instances of my classes to be always constant without *const* keyword? So that I can obtain:

```
indentical(MyClass(), MyClass()); //true (is it possible?)
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Dart 2 allows you to omit `new` everywhere. Anywhere you used to write `new`, you can now omit it.

Dart 2 also allows you to omit `const` in positions where it's implied by the context. Those positions are:

- Inside a `const` object creations, map or list literal (`const [1, [2, 3]]`).
- Inside a const object creation in metadata (`@Foo(Bar())`)
- In the initializer expression of a const variable (`const x = [1];`).
- In a switch case expression (`case Foo(2):...`).

There are two other locations where the language requires constant expressions, but which are not automatically made constant (for various reasons):

1. Optional parameter default values
2. initializer expressions of final fields in classes with `const` constructors

1 is not made const because we want to keep the option of making those expressions not need to be const in the future. 2 is because it's a non-local constraint - there is nothing *around* the expression that signifies that it must be const, so it's too easy to, e.g., remove the `const` from the constructor without noticing that it changes the behavior of the field initializer.

Answer (score 5):

`const` is optional in a *const context*. Basically a *const context* is created when the expression has to be const to avoid compilation error.

In the following snippet you can see some place where `const` is optional:

```
class A {
  const A(o);
}

main(){
  // parameters of const constructors have to be const
  var a = const A(const A());
  var a = const A(A());

  // using const to create local variable 
  const b = const A();
  const b = A();

  // elements of const lists have to be const
  var c = const [const A()];
  var c = const [A()];

  // elements of const maps have to be const
  var d = const {'a': const A()};
  var d = const {'a': A()};
}

// metadatas are const
@A(const A())
@A(A())
class B {}
```

You can find more details in [Optional new/const](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/optional-new-const.md) and [Implicit Creation](https://github.com/dart-lang/sdk/blob/master/docs/language/informal/implicit-creation.md).